# checking if an array has values also in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is structured like this:

```
funActivities(array)
    0(array)
        Activity(array)
            id 4
            name walks
    1(array)
        Activity(array)
            id 5
            name cycling
    2(array)
        Activity(array)
            id 6
            name sand pit
```

and then another like:

```
activities
    0(array)
        id 4
        name walks
    1(array)
        id 6
        name sand pit
```

I want to compare the two arrays and end up with an array which only contains the activities from the 1st array which don't appear in the 2nd array.  So in this case I'd end up with just cycling in the array. It's in the first array, but not the second.

Whats the best way to do that?

Comment: http://php.net/array_intersect

Comment: @AmalMurali `array_diff` would be a closer fit here.

Comment: but if the arrays are structured differently it won't work?

Comment: so you want a array that in your case only have the cycling array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a php function that works for you...

i hope this can help. of course there are some things i could do better but for this szenario it works

```
<?php
$funActivities[0]['Activity']['id']     = 4;
$funActivities[0]['Activity']['name']   = "walks";
$funActivities[1]['Activity']['id']     = 5;
$funActivities[1]['Activity']['name']   = "cycling";
$funActivities[2]['Activity']['id']     = 6;
$funActivities[2]['Activity']['name']   = "sand pit";
$activities[0]['id']    = 4;
$activities[0]['name']  = "walks";
$activities[1]['id']    = 6;
$activities[1]['name']  = "sand pit";

function compareArray($needle,$haystack)
{
    $tmpArray = $haystack;
    foreach($needle as $n)
    {
        $s1 = $n['id'].$n['name'];

        $count = 0;
        foreach($haystack as $h)
        {
            $s2 = $h['Activity']['id'].$h['Activity']['name'];
            if( $s1 == $s2)
            {
                unset($tmpArray[$count]);
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }

    return array_values($tmpArray);
}

$arr = compareArray($activities,$funActivities);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```